Having page numbering with total for every chapter in footer of KOMA-scrreprt with scrlayer-scrpage
I'm using KOMA-class "scrreprt" for creating a long and complicated document, consisting of different separate documents like contracts and information. So far, everything worked out well. I'd like every document, that is organized as a chapter, to have a separate page numbering in the right footer, resulting in page x of n (absolute number of the separate document (=chapter). I've found an instruction from 2008 here https://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?t=2142, but it's not working as intended. Unfortunately, I'm not able to find the mistake or change it by myself to serve the purpose. It's resulting in "page 1 of 3" in the first document, that has only 1 page, the absolute of chapter 2 is 6, but it has only 3 pages, and in document/chapter 3 it says 9 as total page number, but it should be 1.
It would be nice, if it would say page 1 of 1 or better nothing in the footer, if it's only 1 page.
Every help would be much appreciated!
MWE:
\documentclass[
    parskip=half,fontsize=10pt,a4paper,hidelinks,oneside,
    headings=optiontohead%Set class option if the optional argument of sectioning commands (short title) should be used for the page header and not for ToC by default.
    ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % T1-Encoding anstelle von OT1
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol} % mehrere Spalten pro Seite
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=1.7cm, top=1.7cm, footskip=1.2cm]{geometry} % headheight=0.3cm, includehead, includefoot
\usepackage{enumitem}

% Schriftbild
\usepackage{libertine} % Schriftart
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries} % Standardschrift für Überschriften
\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\bfseries\LARGE} % Schrift bei Chapter
\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\bfseries\LARGE} % Schrift bei Section
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalfont\bfseries\large} % Schrift bei Section
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}
\setkomafont{pagefoot}{\normalfont\footnotesize}
%---

% Seitennummerierung
%>>https://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?t=2142
\makeatletter% 
\newcounter{abschapter}
\newcommand*{\normalpagemark}{%
  \renewcommand*{\pagemark}{\usekomafont{pagenumber}\thepage}}
\newcommand*{\chapterpagemark}{%
  \renewcommand*{\pagemark}{\usekomafont{pagenumber}%
    \thepage/\pageref{lastchapterpage.\theabschapter}}}
% Seitennummer am Kapitelanfang auf 1 setzen und die absolute Kapitelnummer
% erhöhen.
\g@addto@macro{\chapterheadstartvskip}{%
  \setcounter{page}{1}%
  \stepcounter{abschapter}%
}
% Vor dem Anfang eines neuen Kapitels ein Label setzen:
\newcommand*{\orig@chapter}{}
\let\orig@chapter\chapter
\renewcommand*{\chapter}{%
  \label{lastchapterpage.\theabschapter}% Label auf der letzten Seite des
                                % vorherigen Kapitels
  \orig@chapter}
% Das gleiche bei Kapiteln, die mit \addchap beginnen
\newcommand*{\orig@addchap}{}
\let\orig@addchap\addchap
\renewcommand*{\addchap}{%
  \label{lastchapterpage.\theabschapter}% Label auf der letzten Seite des
                                % vorherigen Kapitels
  \orig@addchap}
% Und dann noch am Ende des Dokuments
\AtEndDocument{%
  \label{lastchapterpage.\theabschapter}%
}
\makeatother% siehe [url=http://www.golatex.de/wiki/index.php?title=%5Cmakeatother]wiki[/url]
%---

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{}% Chapter-Titel ohne Nummerierung
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}% Chapter-Titel in Kopf-/Fußzeile ohne Nummerierung
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{}% Section-Titel ohne Nummerierung
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{}% Section-Titel in Kopf-/Fußzeile ohne Nummerierung
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\color{protectobronce}}% Chapter-Titel Farbe
\addtokomafont{section}{\centering\color{protectobronce}}% Section-Titel Farbe und Zentrierung
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\color{protectobronce}}% Subsection-Titel Farbe
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}% % Subsection-Titel ohne vorangestellte Section-Nummer

% Inhaltsverzeichnis
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}% level -1: part, 0: chapter, 1: section, 
                    % etc., 5: shows all levels incl. paragraph
\deftocheading{toc}{}%delete title for toc
\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\mdseries}% Don't make chapter 
                                % entries in TOC bold.
\addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\setkomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\nullfont}% keine Seitenzahlen bei Kapiteln im Inhaltsverzeichnis
}%
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocbeforeskip=1ex plus 1pt minus 1pt]{chapter}% change the distance before TOC entries
%\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
%  numwidth=0pt,
%  entrynumberformat=\noentrynumber
%]{chapter}{chapter}% remove chapter numbers from TOC
%---

\usepackage{eso-pic}
    \newcommand\AtPageUpperMyleft[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
     \put(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{-0.5cm}){#1}%
     }}%
    \newcommand\AtPageMyCenter[1]{\AtPageCenter{%
     \put(\LenToUnit{0pt},\LenToUnit{12.5cm}){#1}%
     }}%

\usepackage{graphicx}% stellt \scalebox bereit
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{newgreen}{RGB}{0, 78, 56}
    \definecolor{protectobronce}{RGB}{136, 84, 11}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}% für Tabellen
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pbox}
%\usepackage{lastpage}

% Kopf- und Fußzeile
\usepackage[
  autooneside=false,
  %manualmark,
  headsepline=0pt,% do not use outdated macro \setheadsepline
  footsepline=0pt,% do not use outdated macro \setheadsepline
  plainfootsepline
  ]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
\automark[chapter]{chapter}

\pagestyle{plain} % plain style for all pages except first page

\clearpairofpagestyles% Leeren von Kopf- und Fußzeile
%\ihead{}% Kopfzeile links
%\ohead{}% Kopfzeile rechts
\ifoot*{XXX GmbH}% Fußzeile links
\cfoot*{\headmark}
\ofoot*{Seite \thepage\ von \theabschapter}%\pageref*{LastPage}}% Fußzeile rechts >> \pagemark in the footer

\newcommand*\Introkopf[1]{\chead{#1}}
\Introkopf{%
    \AddToShipoutPictureFG*{
        \AtPageMyCenter{\makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{MWE_logo}}}}%
}
%---

% Vertrag mit KOMA
\usepackage[
    %ref=short
]{scrjura}

\addtokomafont{contract.Clause}{%
    \color{protectobronce} % Color for Clause
    \normalfont\bfseries} % Font for Clause
\setkeys{contract}{%
    preskip=2pt,  % Abstände vor Paragraph-Titeln
    postskip=-5pt} % Abstände nach Paragraph-Titeln
%---

\usepackage[
    colorlinks=false
]{hyperref}

% Formulare
\renewcommand*{\DefaultOptionsofRadio}{print,radio, radiosymbol=6, width=\baselineskip, bordercolor={gray}, borderwidth=0pt}
\renewcommand*{\DefaultOptionsofText}{print,bordercolor={gray}, backgroundcolor=white, borderwidth=0pt}
\renewcommand{\LayoutTextField}[2]{% label, field
\setbox0=\hbox{#1\unskip}\ifdim\wd0=0pt
\setbox1=\hbox{#2\unskip}\ifdim\ht1>3ex
% Multiline
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0}]
  \node[anchor=west] (TextFieldNode) at (0cm,0cm) {#2};
  \draw [thick] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\else
% Inline field, lowered a little bit to be better integrated into the text
\raisebox{-3.2pt}{\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0}]
  \node[anchor=west] (TextFieldNode) at (0cm,0cm) {#2};
  \draw[thick] ([yshift=-0.3ex]TextFieldNode.south west) -- ([yshift=-0.3ex]TextFieldNode.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\fi
\else
% Field with label below it
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0}]
    \node[anchor=west] (TextFieldNode) at (0cm,2ex) {#2};
    \draw[thick] ([yshift=-0.3ex]TextFieldNode.south west) -- ([yshift=-0.3ex]TextFieldNode.south east);
    \node[anchor=west,font=\footnotesize] at (0cm,-0.9ex) {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\fi
}
\newcommand{\field}[2]{\TextField[width=#2]{#1}}
\newcommand{\fieldinline}[2]{\TextField[width=#2,name=#1]{}}
\newcommand{\radiosize}{0.33cm}
\newcommand{\yesnoticks}[1]{%
\raisebox{-3.2pt}{\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0}]
  \node[anchor=west,style={inner sep=2px}] (FieldYes) at (0cm,0cm) {\ChoiceMenu[radio=true,name=#1,width=\radiosize,height=\radiosize]{}{=Yes}};
  \node[anchor=west] (LabelYes) at ([xshift=0.7ex]FieldYes.east) {Yes};
  \node[anchor=west,style={inner sep=2px}] (FieldNo) at ([xshift=1ex]LabelYes.east) {\ChoiceMenu[radio=true,name=#1,width=\radiosize,height=\radiosize]{}{=No}};
  \node[anchor=west] (LabelNo) at ([xshift=0.7ex]FieldNo.east) {No};
  \draw [thick] ([xshift=-(\radiosize+0.15cm),yshift=-(\radiosize+0.15cm)]FieldYes.north east) rectangle (FieldYes.north east);
  \draw [thick] ([xshift=-(\radiosize+0.15cm),yshift=-(\radiosize+0.15cm)]FieldNo.north east) rectangle (FieldNo.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
}
\newcommand{\yesno}[2]{\pbox{0.8\textwidth}{\setstretch{1}#1}\hfill\yesnoticks{#2}}
%---

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INHALT
\begin{document}

\chapter*{Auftrag}
\thispagestyle{scrheadings}% page style scrheadings on first page

Beauftragung der XXX GmbH mit xxx.\\
Gegenstand und Umfang des Auftrags ergeben sich in der Darlegung im Weiteren.

\subsection*{Inhalte dieser Beauftragung}

{\renewcommand\clearpage{}% keine neue Seite für TOC
    \tableofcontents
}

\chapter[Vertrag PK-V01-2024-05-17]{Vertrag}
\thispagestyle{scrheadings}% page style scrheadings on first page

Zwischen

\vspace{0.2cm}

\begin{Form}
\field{Name}{0.34\linewidth}\hfill\field{Vorname}{0.34\linewidth}\hfill\field{Titel}{0.1\linewidth}\hfill\field{Geburtstag}{0.12\linewidth}%

\field{PLZ}{0.1\linewidth}\hfill\field{Wohnort}{0.3\linewidth}\hfill\field{Straße, Hausnummer}{0.5\linewidth}%
\end{Form}

\vspace{-0.5cm}

\begin{flushright}
– im Folgenden \emph{Kunde} –
\end{flushright}

\vspace{-0.5cm}

und der

\vspace{0.2cm}

\textbf{XXX GmbH}, vertreten durch XXX,\\
mit Sitz in Musterstadt, xxx, erreichbar unter xxx

\vspace{-0.5cm}

\begin{flushright}
– im Folgenden \emph{Auftragnehmer} –
\end{flushright}

\vspace{-0.5cm}

wird der im Weiteren dargelegte Vertrag geschlossen.

%\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{contract}

\begin{multicols}{2}

%\minisec{\centering{Rechtliche Stellung}}

%\minisec{\centering\color{protectobronce}{%
%\S~1\\*%
%Vertragsgegenstand}}

\Clause{title={Vertragsgegenstand}}
\label{Vertragsgegenstand}

...

\end{multicols}

\end{contract}

\vspace{0.5cm}

\def\s#1#2{\vbox{\hsize=8cm
    \kern2cm
    \hrule\kern1ex
    \hbox to \hsize{\strut\hfil #1 \hfil}
    \hbox to \hsize{\strut\hfil #2 \hfil}}}

\hbox to \hsize{{%
    \begin{Form}
    \fieldinline{OrtKunde}{5cm}, den \fieldinline{DatumKunde}{2cm}
    \end{Form}}{}\hfil{%
    \begin{Form}
        Musterstadt, den \fieldinline{DatumAuftragnehmer}{2cm}
    \end{Form}
}{}} 

\vspace{-0.5cm}

\hbox to \hsize{\s{Unterschrift Kunde bzw. gesetzlicher Vertreter}{}\hfil
    \s{Unterschrift Auftragnehmer}{}}
    
\chapter[Erstinformation V01-2024-05-17]{Information gemäß \S~XXX — Erstinformation}
\thispagestyle{scrheadings}% page style scrheadings on first page

\begin{multicols}{2}
    
\subsection{Firma und Kontakt}

XXX GmbH\\
Musterstadt

\subsection{Status}

Tätigkeit mit Erlaubnis nach \S~XXX, Registernr. D-XXXX-XXXXX-XX

\subsection{Zulassungs- und Aufsichtsbehörde}

XXX

\subsection{Weiteres}

XXX

...

\end{multicols}

\end{document}


LaTeX has changed too much in this area for a solution from 2008 to work on a recent kernel. When you say the 'absolute of chapter 2', what do you mean? One usage: the absolute page count is the total number of physical (or electronic) pages, regardless of numbering. But that doesn't seem to be what you mean?

I meant a count per chapter, so you'd have page x of y (y being the total page number of the chapter). The solution from cabohah addressed my problem in the way I meant.

Your code has several issues. Some of them like loading several font pages, that clash with each other, are not problem specific, so you should rework your document preamble or start it new from scratch and add only code, that is needed.
Some issues, like using not available external image files or an overburden document preamble with several code not relevant for your main problem, are only problems with making a real minimal working example. Nevertheless you should work on it.
Other issues are relevant for the main problem:

First of all, the assumption that \chapterheadstartvskip can be used as hook to count the absolute number of chapters is wrong. Internally KOMA-Script uses the command several times per chapter. Indeed, when only needing a reference to the last page of the current chapter, this may be less important (and maybe this is the reason the KOMA-Script author has used it in the very old example at a time long before the alternatives have been added to KOMA-Script).

Second, it seems, that you have not understand the meaning of \theabschapter. It is not the number of pages in the current chapter. This would be \pageref{lastchapterpage.\theabschapter}. \theabschapter should be the absolute number of the current chapter (numbered or not). But indeed it is the current absolute number of \chapterheadstartvskip usages (see first issue).

Each usage of \RedeclareSectionCommand[…]{<COMMAND>} redefines not only several internal commands, but also \<COMMAND>. So in your case the late \RedeclareSectionCommand[…]{\chapter} overwrites the previous \renewcommand*{\chapter}. So your extra code when starting a chapter is never used. (Note: I've found this, while minimization of your example after adding one \pageref for debugging.)


All these issues can be solved using do-hooks provided by scrreprt (please see the KOMA-Script manuals for more information and also the meaning of the hooks used below):
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\newcounter{abschapter}% the absolute number of the current (numbered or not
                       % numbered) chapter
\makeatletter
\AddtoDoHook{heading/begingroup/chapter}{% before printing the chapter heading
                                         % but after, e.g., starting the new
                                         % page
  \stepcounter{abschapter}% increase the absolute chapter number
  \setcounter{page}{1}% reset the page counter for per chapter page numbering
  \@gobble% ignore the argument to the hook
}
\AddtoDoHook{heading/preinit/chapter}{% when a new chapter starts, before
                                      % doing anything else
  \label{lastpage.\theabschapter}% write a label with the current absolute
                                 % chapter number
  \@gobble% ignore the argument to the hook
}
\AtEndDocument{\label{lastpage.\theabschapter}}% also write the label at the
                                               % end of the document
\makeatother

\ifoot[last page of absolute chapter \theabschapter: \pageref{lastpage.\theabschapter}]{}
  
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\chapter{Test with number}
\Blindtext[5]
\addchap{Test without number}
\Blindtext[15]
\end{document}

Here you can already see, the meaning of \theabschapter and \pageref{lastpage.\theabschapter}.
So, if you want the absolute number of pages in the current chapter at the chapter starting page, you need something like:
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\newcounter{abschapter}% the absolute number of the current (numbered or not
                       % numbered) chapter
\makeatletter
\AddtoDoHook{heading/begingroup/chapter}{% before printing the chapter heading
                                         % but after, e.g., starting the new
                                         % page
  \stepcounter{abschapter}% increase the absolute chapter number
  \setcounter{page}{1}% reset the page counter for per chapter page numbering
  \@gobble% ignore the argument to the hook
}
\AddtoDoHook{heading/preinit/chapter}{% when a new chapter starts, before
                                      % doing anything else
  \label{lastpage.\theabschapter}% write a label with the current absolute
                                 % chapter number
  \@gobble% ignore the argument to the hook
}
\AtEndDocument{\label{lastpage.\theabschapter}}% also write the label at the
                                               % end of the document
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\chapterpagemark}{\usekomafont{pagination}{\thepage\ / \pageref{lastpage.\theabschapter}}}

\cfoot*{}
\ofoot[\chapterpagemark]{\pagemark}
  
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\chapter{Test with number}
\Blindtext[5]
\addchap{Test without number}
\Blindtext[15]
\end{document}

If you want it not only at the chapter start page, but all pages, use \ofoot*{\chapterpagemark} instead of \ofoot[\chapterpagemark]{\pagemark}.
BTW: When using hyperref you would also need to use, e.g., option pageanchor=false to avoid destination with same identifier errors for the automatically generated page anchors.

Thanks for your answer – it just worked perfectly. Your other advice concerning the other code issues is also much appreciated. I deleted some elements like "[utf8]{inputenc}". Next time the MWE will be better!
